# What is the difference in H:mm:ss and HH:mm:ss in time formats?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to figure out the time format used  on my computer if it is 12hour format or 24hour format and found this solution :

```
Dim strFormat As String = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern
```

The Result is `yyyy'年'M'月'd'日' H:mm:ss`

I am having confusion between this `H:mm:ss` and this `HH:mm:ss`

Is there any difference in the format of the time displayed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any difference in the format of the time displayed?

Yes.

- `HH` is 24-hours, **with** a leading zero for the hours `0-9`.
- `H` is 24-hours **without** a leading zero for the hours `0-9`.

  - Using `H` is not ISO 8601-compliant. ISO 8601 requires 2-digit date and time components with leading zeroes.

So if the current time is `0945h` then `H:mm` will render `9:45`.

So if the current time is `0945h` then `HH:mm` will render `09:45`.

So if the current time is `1945h` then `H:mm` will render `19:45`.

So if the current time is `1945h` then `HH:mm` will render `19:45`.

---

Other important notes:

- `M` and `MM` is months, not minutes.
- `m` and `mm` is minutes not months.

  - There are few (if any) reasons to ever use `m`, so always use `mm`!
- `h` is 12-hour clock hours without a leading zero.

  - Whenever you use `h` you must use `tt` to denote AM/PM, otherwise you'll have ambiguous output.
- `hh` is 12-hour clock hours with a leading zero.

  - Avoid using `hh` because (I believe) that today people expect two-digit times to be using a 24-hour clock.
  - As with `h`, you must also use `tt` to avoid AM/PM ambiguity.

Comment: I see. Then that would be the explanation I needed Sir. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Where can you find more info on the formatting?

Answer (score 0):

h stands for clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12) ,
H stands for hour-of-day (0-23).

Here is the source of truth you can refer to :
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

Thanks,

Shizheng